# How to convert loaded bytes into image without ImageIO.read()

Tags: java, image, http, byte

I can't use ImageIO.read() because of my own restrictions. I can only load bytes after GET request and I need to save this bytes to file as image. But it seems to me, that there also loads some extra data, which browser usually filter (maybe response headers). So I get the array of raw bytes which I even can't open as image.

What should I do with this bytes?

Example:

```
byte[] buf = ContentLoader.loadBytes(new URL("http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg"));
try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\image.jpg"));
            fileOutputStream.write(buf);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

loadBytes() method:

```
public static byte[] loadBytes(URL url) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream boutArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 16];
            while (bin.read(buffer) != -1) {
                boutArray.write(buffer);
                boutArray.flush();
            }
            bin.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return boutArray.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: Why not just store the raw bytes to file?

Comment: Do you want to write your own JPEG decoder? (I've done it, it was a fun exercise) If not, use ImageIO.load (which has one built-in) or find someone else's JPEG decoder.

Comment: When I store raw bytes to file, I can't open it. It contains image bytes and some odd bytes (if to compare size of this image saved by browser and saved by me)

Comment: If your last `read` call returns one byte, you're still writing 16384 bytes (that one byte, plus whatever the other 16383 bytes in the array happened to be from the last chunk).

Comment: @immibis And ditto any other `read()` call. There's no guarantee that any of them fills the buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much for information about odd bytes. You really helped me. I should read more documentation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual problems. The standard way to copy a stream in Java is:

```
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Note that you need to store the result returned by `read()` into a variable; that you need to use it in the next `write()` call; that you shouldn't `flush()` inside a loop; and that you need to close the input and output streams.

And why you're using a `ByteArrayInputStream` at all is a mystery. It's just a waste of time and space. Read directly from the URL input stream, and write directly to the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: I use ByteArrayInputStream because eventually I will need to create BufferedImage, which may take InputStream as an argument. And I can't load it directly by url because of my own restrictions.

Comment: Your own restrictions such as what? You have some objection to using the classes that are provided in the JRE for the purpose?

Comment: I use special library for socks4 support (JRE as it is officially doen'st support socks4 as outdated protocol). That's why I wrote own ContentLoader class which can load data using socks4 proxy. So I can't use ImageIO.read() with my proxy. Now I'm testing the same piece of code, but without proxy, because I know that it will work for socsk4 proxy too. Maybe this way looks a bit complicated, but I don't know any others :)

Comment: What makes you think that Java doesn't support SOCKS 4 any more? The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) says the opposite. and in any case you shouldn't pollute an image loader with SOCKS code, you should keep them entirely separate.

Comment: I know. That's why I want to load the image to ByteArrayOutputStream firstly. And then to use ImageIO.read() and work with it normally.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:-

```
    URL url = new URL("my url...");
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("img.jpg");

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();
```